# head page in previous chapter

Tags: header-footer

Good Afternoon
I am writting my thesis.

In chapters "acknowledgments" , "abstract" etc , I want a head page. How I can put this?

I had a head page in others chapters (after list of tables).  I would like the number page (in roman format) in left side (even pages) and right side (odd pages).

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper,openright]{report}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[lmargin=1.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{emptypage}


\begin{document}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}


\pagenumbering{roman}
\input{Agradecimentos}
\input{Resumo}
\input{Abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\input{Intro}

\end{document}
```

Comment: What exactly is a head page? Where should this page appear and what information should contain? Please describe in more detail what you want to achieve.

Comment: I wanted say "header" in top of page. In "abstract" page, I wanted a header with the name of chapter

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Adding `\fancypagestyle{plain}{}` in the preamble does what you want?

Comment: This is a really wild guess, but i think you want the features defined in [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086)

Comment: As the other comments say, this is really not clear as it stands: please edit and request reopening.