# Non numbered chapter* header issue

Tags: header-footer, chapters

I have a problem with the headers on the second page of my non-numbered chapter. Below is my *minimal* working example.

Everything works but in my Introduction chapter (if I put it without a number as in the example) in the header of the second page (and every other page beyond) I have "list of definitions" instead of "introduction". How can I fix this?

(I also do not like how my glossaries look but I still have to work on that).

Thanks!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,german,english]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier} % Utopia font-typesetting including mathematical formula compatible with newer TeX-Distributions (>2010)
\setlength{\textwidth}{146.8mm} % = 210mm - 37mm - 26.2mm
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{11.6mm} % 37mm - 1in (from hoffset)
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8mm} % = 26.2mm - 1in (from hoffset)
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.2mm} % = 0mm -1in + 23.2mm 
\setlength{\textheight}{221.9mm} % = 297mm -29.5mm -31.6mm - 14mm (12 to accomodate footline with pagenumber)
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyhead[OR]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
    \fancyhead[EL]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
    \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}}
\fancypagestyle{addpagenumbersforpdfimports}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{language=[LaTeX]Tex,tabsize=4, basicstyle=\scriptsize\ttfamily, showstringspaces=false, numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny, numbersep=10pt, breaklines=true, breakautoindent=true, breakindent=10pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfborder={0 0 0},
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=black,
    urlcolor=black}
\urlstyle{same}

\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother \clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}


%%%%% CHAPTER HEADER %%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]  % type (section,chapter,etc...) to vary,  shape (eg display-type)
    {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge} % format of the chapter
    {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}     % the label 
    {0pt} % separation between label and chapter-title
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-8cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle(35.5mm,15mm);
        \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=34mm,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
        {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{15mm}{\raggedleft $\phantom{\textrm{l}}$\color{white}\chapterlabel}};  %the black l is just to get better base-line alingement
        \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-7.2cm,xshift=37mm,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north west)
              {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{\color{black}#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \gdef\chapterlabel{}
  } % code before the title body

\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{30pt}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}  % 13.2pt is line spacing for a text with 11pt font size
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pt}{13.2pt}{*0}

\newcounter{myparts}
\newcommand*\partlabel{}
\titleformat{\part}[display]  % type (section,chapter,etc...) to vary,  shape (eg display-type)
    {\normalfont\bfseries\Huge} % format of the part
    {\gdef\partlabel{\thepart\ }}     % the label 
    {0pt} % separation between label and part-title
      {\setlength{\unitlength}{20mm}
      \addtocounter{myparts}{1}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[anchor=north west,xshift=-65mm,yshift=-6.9cm-\value{myparts}*20mm] at (current page.north east) % for unknown reasons: 3mm missing -> 65 instead of 62
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=black] (0,0) rectangle(62mm,20mm);   % -\value{myparts}\unitlength
        \node[anchor=north west,yshift=-6.1cm-\value{myparts}*20mm,xshift=-60.5mm,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north east)
        {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{55mm}{\raggedright \color{white}Part \partlabel $\phantom{\textrm{l}}$}};  %the phantom l is just to get better base-line alingement
        \node[anchor=north east,yshift=-6.1cm-\value{myparts}*20mm,xshift=-63.5mm,text width=\textwidth,minimum height=30mm,inner sep=0mm] at (current page.north east)
              {\parbox[top][30mm][t]{\textwidth}{\raggedleft \color{black}#1}};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \gdef\partlabel{}
  } % code before the title body


\usepackage{bookmark}% http://ctan.org/pkg/bookmark
\usepackage{booktabs} %ema
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries} %ema 
\usepackage{glossary-mcols} %ema 
\usepackage{glossary-longragged}

\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bm}

\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage{titlesec}  % to set spacings after titles
%\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{1em}{1em}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{1em}{1em}
\titlespacing{\subsubsection}{0pt}{1em}{1em}

% float placement %% from Martin
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.85}   % maximum share of float on top of page
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.1}   % minimum share of text on a page (if both floats and text is present)
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.75} % min share of float on a page that justifies a float-only page. must be smaller than topfraction (and 1-textfraction, i guess)

\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=7
%\graphicspath{{/images}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\thesection}{%
  \ifnum\c@chapter<1 \@arabic\c@section
  \else \thechapter.\@arabic\c@section
  \fi
}
\makeatother

 %to go to a new line after paragraph
\newcommand{\myparagraph}[1]{\paragraph{#1}\mbox{}\\}

% avoid single lines at beginning and end of pages (widows and orphans). increase value up to 1000 if required
\widowpenalty=600
\clubpenalty=600

%avoid splitting footnotes
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\raggedbottom % avoid relative warning


% set distance between text and floats
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{10pt plus 1.0pt minus 2.0pt}



% to number subsub section and make them appear in the toc
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\newcommand*{\Agroupname}{}
\newcommand*{\Ggroupname}{Greek letters}
\newcommand*{\Sgroupname}{Subscripts}

\newglossarystyle{onecol}{%
%
\renewenvironment{theglossary}%
{\begin{description}}{\end{description}}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
%
% indicate what to do at the start of each logical group
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
\item[{\glsgetgrouptitle{##1}}]}
%
\renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\indexspace}%
%
\renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
\item[\glstarget{##1}{##2}] ##3%
}%
}



\newglossary[dlg]{definitions}{dld}{ddn}{List of Definitions}

\newglossaryentry{definition}{name={definition},description={this is a definition},type={definitions}, plural={definitions}}


\immediate\write18{makeglossaries \jobname}
\makeglossaries

\glstoctrue % place your custom packages, etc... in this file!

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% HEAD: Book-Begin
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\cleardoublepage
\pdfbookmark{\contentsname}{toc}
\tableofcontents
\printglossary[type={definitions}]
\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%% MAIN: The chapters of the thesis
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduction}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}
\gls{definition}

\lipsum[3-30]
\glsresetall
\chapter{State of the Art}
 \gls{definition}

\lipsum[7]

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\markboth{}{}`

Comment: Your interpretation of 'minimal' is slightly unusual.

Comment: @Ian, yes i know, i am sorry about that... i modified and tried making it still a bit shorter but i am new to latex. @Johannes_B, thanks for the suggestion... where? is this where the problem is `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}`

Comment: [Book(standard class), headings for chapter\* sections not all caps - urgent help needed](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197961)

Comment: You should make your headers with `titleps` since you use `titlesec` and write a `titleformat` for unnumbered chapters.

Comment: Since you use normal case headings (with `\nouppercase`), just add `\markboth{Introduction}{Introduction}`; for the TOC entry, `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduction}`. Or just take the simplest measure: use `\chapter`! I don't see why the Introduction in the main matter shouldn't be numbered. The objection that “everybody does so” is overruled. `;-)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Starred chapters (and sections) don't get a number, nor a toc entry, nor a header. Problem is, the header is not cleared automatically. You have to do that manually using `\markboth{}{}`. But from your example i can see that you want a toc entry and i think also a header. You could implement that.

A KOMA class provides the same  command in a much more advanced way. Please read [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/193767/correct-use-of-hyperref-and-addcontentsline/193799#193799) to find out more. As of now, you can use the commands like described in the KOMA-script documentation. Changing over to KOMA should not make any difficulties concerning the commands just defined.

To sum it up, `\addchap` makes an annumbered chapter, using its argument for the toc-entry and the header. If an optional argument is given, it is used for toc and head. If the starred form is used, no toc entry will be set and the header will be cleared from any former contents.

---

As this seems to be needed pretty often, i put the former code into a small package called [`unnumberedtotoc`](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc) (<- Downloadlink) which is compatible to KOMA and eases switching later on. This is an alpha version and there might never be any bug-fixes. If you want bullet-proof funtionality, use a KOMA-class.

The package provides just one option; `indentunnumbered`. This is based on package `tocbasic` (from the KOMA bundle).

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[
%   indentunnumbered
]{unnumberedtotoc} %get it from https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{unnumbered chapter with toc and head}
\blindtext[10]

\addchap[title for toc and head]{chapter title}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec*{starred addsec}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec{regular addsec}
\blindtext[10]
\addsec*{starred addsec}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter{usual chapter}
\blindtext[10]
\chapter*{look at the header}
\blindtext[10]
\addchap*{really nothing, header cleared}
\blindtext[10]
\end{document}
```

---

The former example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french,german,english]{babel}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhead[OR]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[EL]{\bfseries \nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[EL,OR]{\thepage}
}
\fancypagestyle{addpagenumbersforpdfimports}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}
}


%Implementing *some* KOMA functionality now
\usepackage{xparse}

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addchap}{ s o m }{%
    \typeout{providing a minimal version of addchapp.
        You might want to use a KOMA class for full
        features
    }%
    \chapter*{#3}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{
        \markboth{}{}
    }{
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#3}
            \markboth{#3}{#3}%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
            \markboth{#2}{#2}%
        }
    }
}

\ProvideDocumentCommand{\addsec}{ s o m }{%
    \typeout{providing a minimal version of addsec.
        You might want to use a KOMA class for full
        features
    }%
    \section*{#2}%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{}{
        \IfNoValueTF{#2}{
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#3}
            \markright{#3}%
        }{%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{#2}
            \markright{#2}%
        }
    }
}





%A KOMA class also provides this feature
\makeatletter
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
    \hbox{}
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \newpage
    \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
    \makeatother \clearpage{\pagestyle{plain}\cleardoublepage}




\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\cleardoublepage
\tableofcontents
%\setlength{\parskip}{0em}
%\setlength{\parindent}{4ex}

\mainmatter
\addchap{Introduction}
\lipsum[3-30]

\addchap[toc and head]{Donald is a great duck}
\lipsum[3-30]
\addsec{Daisy}
\lipsum[3-30]
\addsec{Dagobert}
\lipsum[3-30]
\chapter{State of the Art}

\lipsum[7-20]
\addchap*{really nothing, header cleared}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It worked! I don't want to change class as I am almost done with my document. I wanted the header on every page so I changed to \markboth{#1}{#1}. I also have sections in the introduction so I defined the \addsec as you defined the \addchap. The only small thing I still would like to have is the name of the section on the right (odd pages) and the name of the chapter on the left (even pages). I guess I have to change \markboth{??}{#1}.. with something instead of ?? If you could help me with that... then I am sorted.

Comment: @esperluette See the update :-)