# how to add preface to table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents, align, page-numbering

I am trying to add a preface section to the table of contents, by using

```
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
```

This partially works. the preface is added, but without the page number for it (in roman letters, it should be, because it is in the frontmatter section).

In addition, the Preface line (which doesn't appear with a page number) is not aligned with the rest of the text for the chapters, since I use chapter* for it, and therefore, there is no number before it.

So it appears as:

```
      Preface
      1 Introduction
```

instead of

```
        Preface
      1 Introduction
```

When I look into the .toc file, I see:

```
     \contentsline {chapter}{Preface}{x}{chapter*.1}
     \contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}{Introduction}}{1}{chapter.1}
```

so obviously I can hack it to add a line number, I guess, but I would like to avoid it. I am not sure how to fix the alignment problem, though, through the .toc file (though, again, I wouldn't want to touch the .toc files).

Comment: [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086)

Comment: The solution to your problem is relevant to the documentclass in use. Without this information, best in form of a minimal working example, everything will be just guesswork.

Comment: Touching the `.toc` files is useless as they are regenerated during any compilation run, unless `\nofiles` is used.

Comment: If using a KOMA class, you can save yourself a lot of trouble: [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799)

Answer (score 4):

Just a wild guess, but you could use package `unnumberedtotoc` with option `indentunnumbered` found in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086/37907.

As you didn't provide any useful code, this is just guesswork.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[indentunnumbered]{unnumberedtotoc}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\addchap{Preface}
\blindtext[13]
\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[13]
\end{document}
```

[image]