# fancyhdr: Wrong page number for chapter* in the prefix

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, koma-script, fancyhdr

In my thesis I have a list of abbreviations between the list of tables and the first chapter. I want to continue the page numbering from the other prefix parts (roman) and then switch to arabic with the first page of the introduction.

I use `fancyhdr` and redefined the plain settings, which works great for everything except for my list of abbreviations.

The page right before is the list of tables with page number iii and the first page of the abbreviations has a iv. However, the second page of the list of abbreviations suddenly starts with a 1, followed by a 2 on the next page.

How do I get roman numbers for all pages of the abbreviations? The list is done using `longtable`. I tested using `tabbing` too and had the same problem.

My document class is `\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,oneside, numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}`

Here are my fancyhdr settings:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter \quad \ #1}}{}}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \fancyhf{} % clear all header and footer fields
    \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage} %pagenumber on chapter pages,
    }

\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
```

The prefix part of the main document looks like this:

```
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of contents}
\tableofcontents
\pagenumbering{roman} %start page numbering i, ii, iii, ...
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{List of Figures}
\cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename} %list of figures in table of content
 \listoffigures
 \renewcommand{\listtablename}{List of Tables}
 \cleardoublepage
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename} %list of tables in table of content
 \listoftables 
 \cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations} 
\input{pre/listA.tex}
```

and the input pre/listA.tex looks like this:

```
\chapter*{List of Abbreviations}

\markboth{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}{List of Abbreviations}
\pagenumbering{roman} \setcounter{page}{4}

\section*{Symbols and units} 

\begin{longtable}{lll}

    $a_s$ & Angstrom constant - clear-sky days [-]  \\
    $b_s$ & Angstrom constant - completely overcast days [-] \\
\end{longtable}

\section*{Abbreviations}

\begin{tabular}{ll}

    ASCE & American Society of Civil Engineers \\
    \end{tabular}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
    \markboth{\MakeUppercase{\thechapter \quad \ #1}}{}}
```

Comment: Please make your code into a complete, small document which people can copy-paste-compile to reproduce the issue. This is much more useful than mere code fragments. By the way, you would be better advised to use the facilities of Koma's built-in interface for configuring headers etc. rather than loading additional packages which will break various features and probably cause both confusion and inconsistencies.

Comment: You are using a KOMA-class, use it the right way. `listof=totoc`. Package `fancyhdr` should *not* be used with KOMA-script, KOMA provides `scrlayer-scrpage` itself. If you want unnumbered chapters in the toc use, package [unnumberedtotoc](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/199071/non-numbered-chapter-header-issue/199086#199086) or have a look at [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799) directly. You don't have to issue `cleardoublepage`s after/before a new chapter.

Comment: With an up to date version of KOMA script, you can get the pagenumber at the outer head by using `ohead*{\pagemark}` for plain pages as well. But please be aware, that onesided document only have *right-hand* pages.

Answer (score 1):

By chance I discovered that my problem is solved if I add an empty input after the list of abbreviations:

```
 \cleardoublepage
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations} 
\input{pre/listA.tex}
\input{pre/test1.tex}
```

where test1.tex consists of:

```
\newpage
```