# Hide section number but keep in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

I want to hide a section number in the headings of section like this:

```
\section*{Abstract}
```

Turns out if I put an asterisk in the section command like this, the number is not present in the heading and also there is no entry  in the table of contents, but I want the heading to remain in the table of contents. How to do this.

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/johannesbottcher/unnumberedtotoc

Comment: Related: [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086) and [How to use unnumbered chapters with KOMA-script?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193799)