# How can I correct Header in latex?

Tags: header-footer

I am using LaTeX for preparing by project. I am using `\documentclass{report}`

As I am in need of first chapter Introduction' with no chapter number i have used

```
\newcommand{\mychapter}[2]{
        \setcounter{chapter}{#1}
        \setcounter{section}{0}
        \chapter*{#2}
        \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#2}
    }
```

in preamble.

As i am in need of list of figures before the introduction   after `\begin{document}` i have added following comments

```
\listoffigures

\mychapter{0}{Introduction}
In Chapter 1, we give the basic ideas and facts.....
```

and in the out put the Header of the chapter introduction is List of figures. (See Figure). May any one help to recover from this issue.

'[image]

Comment: Your `\mychapter` command is almost certainly not the best way to do what you want to do. But in order for someone to offer a better solution, you're probably going to need to edit your question to provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)).

Comment: [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a better definition for `\mychapter`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for mock text

\pagestyle{headings} % to get headers

\newcounter{savedsecnumdepth}

\newcommand{\mychapter}[1]{%
  \setcounter{savedsecnumdepth}{\value{secnumdepth}}%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1000}%
  \chapter{#1}%
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{\value{savedsecnumdepth}}%
  \refstepcounter{chapter}%
}

\setcounter{chapter}{-1}% first should be Chapter 0
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\mychapter{Introduction}

\section{Ghijk}

\kant[1-30]

\end{document}
```

[image]