# Chapter headings list of tables

Tags: header-footer

I realized today that the chapter "Introduction" has "List of Tables" as header.
I use this code to add the chapter "Introduction"

```
\chapter*{Introduzione}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduzione}\pagenumbering{Roman}
```

This chapter has two pages. Both have roman numbers, but the second has as header "List of Tables" instead of "Introduction".

I use `\listoftables` to create the list and `\input{introduction}` to call the file in the main one.
The same thing happen with another chapter that uses `\chapter*`; on the header there is the name of the previous chapter (that is created with `\chapter`

```
\RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[a4paper,italian,oneside,openright,12pt,draft]{book}
\usepackage{cmap} % makes PDF searchable
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} % Latin Modern font
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp} % needed for fontenc
\usepackage[bookmarksnumbered,final]{easyoutput}
\usepackage[binding=0.8cm]{layaureo}  % migliore copertura foglio A4 + margine rilegatura
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath, bm}
\usepackage[font={it}]{caption}

\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeindex
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} %aggiunge bibliografia nell'indice senza l'elenco delle immagini e tabelle
\usepackage{hyperref}


% righe sull'header delle pagine
\fancyhf{}
\lhead{\leftmark}
\rhead{\thepage}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% tabelle
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{pbox}
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
%%%% title and other stuff %%%%
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\input{dedica}
\input{introduzione}
\cleardoublepage
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\input{capitolo1}
\input{capitolo2}
\input{capitolo3}
\input{capitolo4}
\input{conclusioni}

\backmatter

\medskip

\bibliographystyle{unsrt-custom}
\bibliography{bibliografia}
\input{immagini}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\markboth{}{}\cleardoublepage` before your `\chapter*` command, I assume

Comment: try  `\chapter*{Introduzione}
\markboth{}{}`

Comment: Disappears the title on the header with this. I want the title if it's possible,

Comment: @Shika93: Provide the code then, the minimal version that is compilable and has this issue

Comment: Maybe you want`\chapter*{Introduzione} \markboth{Introduzione}{}`.

Comment: [Non numbered chapter\* header issue](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199086) Without any warranty.

Comment: Thank you esdd. I didn't read how `\markboth` works. Thank you all!

Comment: Why aren't you using the `book` class? You would have much less issues and won't need manual adjustments.

Comment: I am using `book` class. I'll add the preamble even if you solved my problem